# apt --fix-broken install does not work, package manager broken after installing wine-stable

Tags: package-managers, broken-pipe

after **uninstalling** old version of **wine-1.8** and installing it again, I encountered an **ERROR** in package manager for **Broken packages**:

```
Preparing to unpack .../libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwine:amd64 (3.0-1ubuntu1) ...

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wine/acledit.dll.so', which is also in package wine1.8-amd64 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1

dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libwine:i386 (3.0-1ubuntu1) ...

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine/acledit.dll.so', which is also in package wine1.8-i386:i386 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1

dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `sudo apt autoremove` worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I **SOLVED** this problem with the following **solution**:

```
sudo dpkg --force depends -P wine1.8-i386
sudo dpkg --force depends -P wine1.8
sudo dpkg --force depends -P wine1.8-amd64
```

and finally you need to run this command **to** **fix** **all broken packages**:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

(for more reference check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067430/apt-fix-broken-install-does-not-work-package-manager-broken-after-installing) out.)

Comment: Awesome solution, appreciated. This happened to me with _i915_dri.so_, using that forced dependency on _libgl1-amber-dri_ (just one line) allowed to fix the broken ones. This was likely caused by updating Brave browser through _apt_.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that the time I spend to find the solution, saved your's!:)